# How to remove manually tensors from memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management

I have some trouble with how tensorflow handle memory. I would like to remove tensors from my memory after each iteration on this toy example.

I am using tensorflow EagerExecution. I have tried with Variables and with simple tensors. tf.assign doesn't do the job. More and more memory is used. I guess it's normal in order to be able to compute the gradient. Even if I apply some dummy optimizer at the end of each iteration, the memory isn't not released (more precisely, it happens sometimes but the global trend is that the memory use is growing).

So is it possible to delete manually ?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
import numpy as np
import time as ti


tf.enable_eager_execution()

for i in range(150):
    all_subject=tfe.Variable(np.random.rand(200, 500), dtype=tf.float32)
    tf.assign(all_subject, np.random.rand(200,500) )
    ti.sleep(1.0)
    del all_subject
    ti.sleep(0.5)
```

What the allocation looks like :

[Memory profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v8a3.png)

Comment: You shouldn't create a variable in each iteration, create it once before the loop and reuse inside.

Comment: @jdehesa this is supposed to be okay in eager.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation on eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager#use_objects_for_state_during_eager_execution),

> During eager execution the lifetime of state objects is determined by the lifetime of their corresponding Python object.

So you should not observe any memory leak in your code, even without an explicit `del`: the simple fact of reassigning your variable to something else should free the memory.

However, this is not what happen and I observe the same memory leak as you.

So this could be a (serious) bug, which you could submit [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

Comment: Yes i agree, the del thing was just to make the problem highlighted.

So I will

Comment: Has this been solved? Or is this still an issue? I am currently not using any `del` in my codes, but might use it in the future.